# Shapes in C++ Programs

Tags: c++

If I recall correctly, I saw some ungodly C++ library that let you type ASCII-art shapes in C++ programs and treat them as objects.  Something like this:

```
int area = someFreakyClass(o-----o
                           |     |
                           o-----o).area();
```

What was this library called?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Analog Literals](http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/analogliterals.xhtml) by Eelis.

Answer (score 10):

Improved version of Analog Literals:

[Tweaking Analog Literals (C++ humor)](http://hostilefork.com/2009/08/29/tweakinganalog-literals-humor/)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
 int area = someFreakyClass(_________________________________________________
                    /|     |                                                 |
                    ||     |                                                 |
               .----|-----,|                                                 |
               ||  ||   ==||                                                 |
          .-----'--'|   ==||                                                 |
          |)-      ~|     ||_________________________________________________|
          | ___     |     |____...==..._  >\______________________________|
     [_/.-.\"--"-------- //.-.  .-.\\/   |/            \\ .-.  .-. //
       ( o )`==="""""""""`( o )( o )     o              `( o )( o )`
        '-'                '-'  '-'                       '-'  '-').area();
```

Comment: `velocity()` would be more interesting…

Comment: Or `number_of_wheels()`.